# XPath select descendants except nested

Tags: xpath, nested

I want to select all "target" elements which contain somewhere a "condition" element. So far it's easy: "//target[descendant::condition]"

The problem is: My "target" elements are nested and I DON'T want to select those "target" elements in which one ore more "condition" elements is just inside another "target" element.

See, my XML looks like this

```
<ROOT>

<target id="1">
 <condition/>
</target>

<target id="2">
 <any_tag/>
</target>

<target id="3">
 <condition/>
 <target id="4">
   <condition>
 </target>
</target>

<target id="5">
 <target id="6">
  <condition/>
 </target>
</target>

</ROOT>
```

I want to select the "target" elements with the ids 1, 3, 4 and 6 but NOT 5 because between this `<target>` tag and the "condition" tag there is another "target" tag.

(In my real code, a "condition" element is nowhere a direct child of a "target" element. I changed that for reasons of simplifying .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ancestor` in this case

```
//condition/ancestor::target[1]
```

You should use `[1]` to select only first ancestor of each `condition`.

Comment: I thought of this, but I assumed that this could select some "target" elements more than once, because in some cases there are more than one "condition" elements there. But somehow it works! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it is possible to select one element more than once. That's why it works. You're welcome.